# Which Stack Exchange site has the longest name?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, domain-names

Which Stack Exchange site has the longest name? Does Area 51 have a limit on proposal names? I need to know this for my [userscript](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MinimalOverflow).

Comment: Try [this](http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites).

Comment: Do you need this because of a userscript you're writing, or something?

Comment: @PopularDemand - Yes, I needed it for the minimalist userscript.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The longest SE site names currently are:

```
Code Golf and Programming Puzzles (33)
Audio Recording and Production    (30)  
Theoretical Computer Science      (28)  
Science Fiction and Fantasy       (27)  
English Language and Usage        (26)  
Personal Finance and Money        (26)
```

The longest SE site URLs are:

```
https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com (50)
https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com  (49)
https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com  (49)
https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com   (48)
...
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com      (45) Longest full SE site
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com       (44)
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com       (44)
https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com        (43)
...
https://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com                (35) Longest chat sites
https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com                (35) Longest chat sites
```

Comment: This is the info I'm looking for. I dare someone to make a "Supercalfragilisticexpialidocious" proposal just to spite me.

Comment: Code Golf has the longest name? The irony!

Answer (score 8):

Area 51 does have a limit on the topic field, which you can see by typing in the form:

[image: Create proposal, topic field]

The [API](http://stackapps.com) does not put hard limits on fields, and they are subject to change, however the documentation does list a suggested size.  For the sites, you can see this by going to http://stackauth.com/1.0/help/method?method=sites

So, even between the two, the limits are different, and those numbers aren't carved in stone.

Comment: The 1.0 API no longer exists, probably use [/2.2/sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites) today.

Answer (score 6):

For forwards-compatibilities sake, here's a way to find out in Python:

```
compressed = urllib.urlopen('http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites')
uncompressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj = StringIO.StringIO(compressed.read()))
data = json.load(uncompressed)
print max([site['name'] for site in data['api_sites'] if site['state'] == 'normal'], key = lambda x: len(x))
```

You can let `state` be `open_beta` and `closed_beta` if you want to count those

Comment: that url is now dead. I guess that went to stackapps.com https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage the [Stack Exchange 2.2 API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). It has an end-point [/sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=500&filter=default&run=true) that returns all the main and meta sites in the network.

In the following userscript that end point is used to fetch all sites and then filter the result so only the main sites remain. Next that list is sorted on its length in descending order. Finally that list is added to an html table  so the result can be inspected.

When run today (Aug 30th, 2020) the site with the longest name is [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com) with a length of 36 characters.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434
// User Wladimir Palant https://stackoverflow.com/users/785541/wladimir-palant
function decode(txt) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}


function buildIconCell(site) {
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src= site.high_resolution_icon_url;
  cell.appendChild(img);
  return cell;
}


function buildNameCell(site) {
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = site.site_url;
  link.innerHTML = site.name;
  link.title = decode(site.audience);
  cell.appendChild(link);
  return cell;
}

function buildNameLengthCell(site) {
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.innerHTML = decode(site.name).length;
  return cell;
}

function buildRow(site) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.appendChild(buildIconCell(site));
  row.appendChild(buildNameCell(site));
  row.appendChild(buildNameLengthCell(site));
  
  return row;
}

function add(site) {
  document.getElementById('result').appendChild(buildRow(site));
}

function getMainSitesSorted(data) {
   var sites = data.items.filter(function(item) { return item.site_type === 'main_site' });
    sites.sort(function(l,r) {
      var lName = decode(l.name);
      var rName = decode(r.name);
      return lName.length < rName.length ? 1 : lName.length > rName.length? -1 : 0;
    });
  return sites;
}

function process() {
  if (xhr.status >199 && xhr.status < 300) {
    document.getElementById('error').textContent = null;
    document.getElementById('content').style.display='block';
    
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    
    var sites = getMainSitesSorted(data);
    for(var i=0; i< sites.length ; i = i + 1) {
      add(sites[i]);
    }
  } else {
     error();
  }
}


function error() {
  document.getElementById('error').textContent = 'Something went wrong'; 
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=500&key=JBN9WXWxwrcnAj7WEEytmQ((');
xhr.addEventListener('load', process);
xhr.addEventListener('error', error);
xhr.send();
```

```css
img {
width: 2em;
}
th, td {
 padding: 0.1em;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align:right;
}

#content {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="error" class="error">Loading ...</div>
<div id="content">
  <table>
    <thead><tr><th></th><th>Site</th><th>Length</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody id="result">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

In general new sites launch on a Tuesday nor do name changes happen every 6 to 8 week so you won't need to run this script very often ...

Comment: Argh! I was always proud of the long name of Code Golf.