# What's the longest tag (among all SE sites)?

Tags: discussion, tags, statistics

This question is similar to [Which SE site has the longest name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80911/which-se-site-has-the-longest-name) but regarding tag titles.

Is there any quick way to determine the longest tag titles?
Also, is there any length limit on tag titles?

I'm designing a UI and this info would help me to eliminate some boundary cases...

Comment: Just found 'nsfetchedresultscontrolle' tag on SO, obviously missing the last (26th) 'r' character. I assume S.Mark's 25 length limit is right then :)

Comment: we do indeed limit tags to 25 characters at many levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably 25 according to [api help](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=tags)

```
"values": "string",
"suggested_buffer_size": 25
```

Comment: Exactly 25. Looking at `Tags` table at data.stackexchange.com, `TagName` is of type `nvarchar(25)`, so it gets truncated when longer.